# How can i integrate mastercard sdk in ios

Tags: swift, xcode, mastercard

i have project must be integrate mastercard sdk with my project. My question there is any article or videos explain to me Steps how can i create account in mastercard and connect it with my account and integrate mastercard sdk.
Thank you very much

Comment: did you check out the Masterpass checkout iOS SDK documentation? - https://developer.mastercard.com/page/masterpass-merchant-ios-sdk-v25

Comment: Yes but my problem is how can i connect my personal account in my country with masters card Acount this is the problem for transferring money to my account